# how to pass a variable from preDispatch to controller and action?

Tags: php, web-services, api, zend-framework, rest

I try to put a variable in preDispatch function that check login, and I want to pass this variable to controllers (for Action to use).

I just try `$this->getRequest()->setParam('check_login', 'FALSE');`

But it doesn't work ...

Do anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

if you have no particular reason to pass the variable in the request object assign that variable to a private or protected member:

```
<?php
class my_Controller extends blah blah
{
    protected $login; 

    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->login = what it needs to be
    }
}
```

However the code you present works for me. Except for one small item. If you wish to use **'FALSE'** as a boolean you may need to remove the quotes. The way it is presented at the moment **'FALSE'** is a string and may not work properly as a boolean operator.

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('check_login', FALSE);
```